# "Hard Cutting" makes strips disappear randomly

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Sometimes, when I hard cut a strip in the VSE, instead of simply cutting the strip in two, Blender will delete one of the two halves (afaict, there is no pattern as to which of the two halves will be deleted). Sometimes, also the other strip will "loose" a bit.

**Question**: Is this a bug or a feature, and how can I avoid it (besides using soft cut instead)?

Comment: could show an image, gif or upload the  blend file. And ar you using a shortcut (if yes, which one).

Comment: I don't have an image available at the moment. I use the keyboard command "Shift-K" for hard cutting.

Comment: have you ever thee shortcut "K"

Comment: What kind of media does this happen to and what version of Blender are you using on which OS?

Comment: @3pointedit This appears with both video and audio strips. It usually seems to occur (only occurs) when I have selected multiple strips and cut them at the same time. I'm on Win XP, Blender 2.76 at the moment (has happened with several older versions as well).

Comment: Could be a mis handling of the media depending on the codec. I would suggest trying B2.78 but use a copy of the project in case you want to go back to the old version as they won't be backward compatible I expect.

Comment: Try a differently encoded video file. This sort of squirley behaviour could be because Blender doesn't like frame rate variable encoded media, like screen captures. You could try transcoding the footage to a more stable codec.

Comment: All my videos have a constant framerate. Also, it does not only affect videos.